# Migrate from Magento Enterprise to Community

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system

I had a question regarding Magento: -

Currently I have a client whose online site and catalog was being built on magento, however they are wanting to divide up their site to use a different platform for the catalog management and consumer purchasing experience, while keeping the rest of their corporate site intact on magento.

Since they were using enterprise before, the idea is to move to Community to use for their corporate site, however I'm wondering if this is feasible to do from a migration standpoint. Is there any way to port across their CMS pages (catalog isn't important) from their old enterprise version to a fresh community version, and have it remain intact?

Comment: Try to use previous DB on community files. This should work.

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise has lots of additional features in place. Also its URL table are modified. So you need to check if these features are used in design.If so you need to remove all those plus you might have to move some data or populate some tables.

Its possible to move back from enterprise to community.But is not a cake walk.